# E-mail de ativação

Tags: codeigniter

Tenho um cadastro de usuários o qual envia por e-mail os dados preenchidos corretamente.

Agora queria um link que vá junto por e-mail para ativação do usuário. Só após clicar no link o usuário passaria a ser devidamente reconhecido pelo sistema.

Como poderia fazer isso, se possível, com o CodeIgniter que já uso?

Comment: Olá Eduardo, tudo bem? Você poderia atualizar a sua pergunta com enxertos de código demonstrando sua estratégia de envio de e-mails durante a criação do usuário? Se você puder comentar mais sobre que problema em específico você está tendo na hora de incluir um link para a ativação do usuário isso também ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Não vou responder com base no CodeIgniter tanto pelo fato de não trabalhar com o CodeIgniter e também porque isso limitaria a utilização da resposta apenas àqueles que usam essse framework.

Ativação de usuário depende de condicionar o valor de uma determinada coluna no registro do usuário, então, se esta ainda não existe, você deve criá-la.

Pode ser até mesmo um campo do tipo CHAR, afinal armazenaríamos nele apenas um inteiro-booleano 0 (zero) caso o usuário não tenha sio ativado e 1 (um) caso tenha. Para o propósito da resposta, chamaremos esse campo de **isActive**.

O link de ativação deve conter algum valor a ser condicionado para efetuar o UPDATE. Pode ser até mesmo o ID do usuário, mas se você precisar de um pouco mais de segurança, continue lendo mais abaixo.

Mandar o e-mail, você já sabe como fazer então basta incluir no corpo da mensagem um link o qual represente uma ação válida na sua Aplicação, como:

```
domain.com/users/activate/123
```

Na ação correspondente à esse link você consulta o registro referente ao ID recebido (WHERE). Se encontrado, você verifica o valor da nossa coluna **isActive**. Se for igual a zero, você faz o UPDATE:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `isActive` = 1 WHERE ID = XXX
```

Obviamente que XXX é o valor recebido.

Se já for igual a 1 (um), você exibe uma mensagem de erro ou aviso de que aquele usuário já está ativado.

Desse ponto em diante, qualquer ação na sua Aplicação que dependa do usuário estar ativo no seu sistema, você verifica se o valor dessa *flag* é 1 (um).

Porém nem todos os recursos precisam dessa verificação. A edição do Perfil do usuário, por exemplo, é um desses casos (se aplicável).

Quanto a questão da segurança adicional, você pode ter uma coluna extra no registro do usuário com um *hash* único para cada usuário. Esse *hash* pode ser qualquer coisa, como um [uniqid()](http://php.net/uniqid) gerado no momento do cadastro..

Ao invés de no e-mail você enviar o ID do usuário (e consequentemente condicionar a ativação com esse mesmo valor), você usa esse hash que, teoricamente é mais difícil de se violar que um inteiro simples.

Comment: Este exemplo usando um uniqid() é muito bom pois possibilita de maneira facil comparar aquilo que vem do link de ativação com o que esta no db do usuário...fazendo assim validação caso seja igual :)

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>**TBL-USERS**</sub>
>   <sub>nome | email | ... | status | code-validate</sub>

Quando o usuário for inserido no DB, será criada uma hash qualquer que você pode gravar no `code-validate` e o `status` mantém em off. O e-mail vai com um link e a referência do `code-validate`, algo do tipo: `site.com/user/active?XXX`.

Na página active você vai validar o `code-validate` e mudar o `status` do user para true.